# jQuery animating div to each corner ends in jumpy animation and 'fixed' element

Tags: jquery, css, animation

Link: http://jsfiddle.net/kbJCc/1/

Unfortunately I can't even perform the most simple animation with jquery right now.
I've got a quadratic div separated in 4 buttons. Each button represents one corner of my screen. So if I press btn1 my quadrativ div should animate to the upper-left corner.
btn2 should animate the div to the upper-right. btn3 bottom left a.s.o.

Now there are two problems:
1. animation is not smooth in safari & chrome (it jumps from one corner to an other)
2. If I have clicked all (one after the previous animation) the div is stuck in the upper left corner.

Firebug told me that my div keeps all of the css rules applied by $.animate()?!

Hopefully someone out here can help me.

Thank you so much.

Btw. the div initially should have been centered on my window :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have updated [your jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kbJCc/4/). Basically, I gave the element containing `main-menu` static dimensions so that the JavaScript has something from which to calculate positions. I then initialized the `main-menu` element to the "center" of the document via JavaScript once the DOM is ready (technically, this could, and should, be done in the stylesheet). Finally, I updated your animations to explicitly animate all sides of the `main-menu` element.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `animate` smoothly transitions css properties from their current values to your specified values.  Since `bottom` isn't set initially, for example, clicking on the bottom-left button will animate `bottom` from `0` to `10px` rather than animating `top`.

To work around this, you could deal exclusively with only animating `top` and `left`.  Another option is to initialize the CSS property before starting the animation.

Answer (score 0):

Very simple way to do

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [startAnimate, setStartAnimate] = useState(false);
  const animate = () => {

    setStartAnimate(!startAnimate);
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div class={`logo ${startAnimate && "animate"}`}></div>
      <button onClick={animate}>click</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

css

```
}
.logo {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20%;
  left: 50%;
  right: 0;
  background-color: red;
  transition: all 1s;
}
.logo.animate {
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  transform: scaleY(0.5);
}
```

[sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/upbeat-lederberg-ojdd0?file=/src/styles.css:56-269)