# Animate logo from middle of the screen to left corner

Tags: css, reactjs, css-animations

#### Problem

Currently I am looking for a way to animate an image in [react](/questions/tagged/react) from the center of the screen to the upper left corner in a nice smooth way. I have been searching on SO and Google for a while, but couldn't find a way to do it. Only one jquery related fiddle I found here: [jQuery animating div to each corner ends in jumpy animation and 'fixed' element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4788708/jquery-animating-div-to-each-corner-ends-in-jumpy-animation-and-fixed-element)

#### Animation

[video](https://streamable.com/4x56fn)

#### Toolbelt

- [react.js](/questions/tagged/react.js) as language
- [jsx](/questions/tagged/jsx) as templating language
- [sas](/questions/tagged/sas)s as a preprocessor